# Motivation behind the definition of reflections in affine hyperplane

Tags: geometry, definition

What is the motivation behind the definition of the reflection map in affine hyperplanes? $R: x \to x-2(x\cdot u-c)u$ where $u\cdot x=c$ defines the affine plane.

Of course one requirement is for it to be consistent with the usual $R^3$ reflections... Where does the extra $2cu$ term come from? To preserve isometry?

Answer (score 2):

The $2cu$ term is the only term that it not linear in $x$ -- it makes sure that the affine plane in question maps to itself. Otherwise the reflection would reflect about a hyperplane *through the origin* but parallel to chosen hyperplane.

(Also note that the definition only works when the equation of the plane is normalized such that $|u|=1$).